# Decode json with dynamic coding key using Codable?

Tags: json, swift, decode, codable

Example of Json I need to decode. In "text" key we have [String: String] dict. And quantity of elements is in "count". How should I decode it properly?

```
{
"name": "LoremIpsum",
"index": "1",
"text": {
    "text_1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
    "text_2": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ",
    "text_3": "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. ",
    "text_4": "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
},
"count": "4"
}
```

My Codable model:

```
class Text: Codable {

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name, index, count, text
}

public var name: String?
public var index: Int?
public var count: Int?
public var texts: [String]?

init() {
    name = ""
    index = 0
    count = 0
    texts = []
}

init(name: String,
     index: Int,
     count: Int,
     texts: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.index = index
    self.count = count
    self.texts = texts
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    var text = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: . text)

}    <---- also why do I need this method? 

required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.index = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .index)) ?? 0
    self.count = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .count)) ?? 0
    let text = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .text)

    for i in (1...self.count!) {
        self.texts!.append(try text.decode(String.self, forKey: Text.CodingKeys.init(rawValue: "text_\(i)") ?? .text))
    }
}

}
```

And I decode it with:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en_translation_001", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            let jsonObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(Text.self, from: data)
            print("jsonData:\(jsonObj)")
        } catch let error {
            print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
```

But I got parse error

> parse error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

What is wrong with my code? Is it a good way to decode such dynamic coding keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let name, index,count: String
    let text: [String:String]
}
```

--

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:jsonData)
```

Comment: The thing is that there can be text5, text6 and textN
Depending on "count"

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev use only that struct and the decode should work

Answer (score 2):

#### **Fix JSON**

I suppose you want your index and count to be numbers. So replace this `"index": "1"` and this `"count": "4"`
With this `"index": 1` and this `"count": 4`

#### **Class structure**

With Codable protocol any of these CodingKeys and encode functions or required inits aren't neccessary. Also change texts property data format to [String: String]

So, replace your class like this:

```
class Text: Codable {

    public var name: String
    public var index: Int
    public var count: Int
    public var texts: [String: String]

    init(name: String, index: Int, count: Int, texts: [String: String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.index = index
        self.count = count
        self.texts = texts
    }

}
```

#### **Decoding**

For decoding your json use what you wrote above, this is correct

```
let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(Text.self, from: data)
```

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev Read edited answer. You were decoding your json right, but your class was wrong.

Comment: index and count are not ints plus texts is a dictionary not array

Comment: I need to remove all inits and also 
"init(from decoder: Decoder)" ?

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev if you want to, you can keep your init(name: String....

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev btw, try to fix json as I wrote above

Comment: @Sh_Khan you are right, I've changed it. But you were faster. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing you need is this:

```
let text = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .text)
texts = try text.allKeys.map { try text.decode(String.self, forKey: $0) }
```

This will convert the dictionary into an array of values. While in principle JSON values are not ordered, `allKeys` is ordered (because it's a serialized protocol).

You wouldn't need the encode method if you conformed only to `Decodable` rather than `Codable`. Also, most of your optionals are not really optionals.

Putting those things together, you would have this:

```
class Text: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, index, count, text
    }

    public var name: String
    public var index: Int
    public var count: Int
    public var texts: [String]

    init(name: String = "",
         index: Int = 0,
         count: Int = 0,
         texts: [String] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.index = index
        self.count = count
        self.texts = texts
    }

    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.index = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .index)) ?? 0
        self.count = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .count)) ?? 0
        let text = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .text)
        texts = try text.allKeys.map { try text.decode(String.self, forKey: $0) }
    }

}

let jsonObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(Text.self, from: data)
```

Comment: I think this should be a server response fix not a local code